# Which two elements of $Z_2 \times Z_4$ might you use to generate all of $Z_2 \times Z_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, sagemath

In Judson *Abstract Algebra: Theory and Applications*, p. 176, one can read:

*Build the permutation representation of $Z_2 \times Z_4$ described in Cayley’s Theorem [...]*

I got to this point with Sage (after some pen and paper work):

```
G = PermutationGroup([
    '()',
    '(1,2,3,4)(5,6,7,8)',
    '(1,3)(2,4)(5,7)(6,8)',
    '(1,4,3,2)(5,8,7,6)',
    '(1,5)(2,6)(3,7)(4,8)',
    '(1,6,3,8)(2,7,4,5)',
    '(1,7)(2,8)(3,5)(4,6)',
    '(1,8,3,6)(2,5,4,7)'
])
```

I think this is fine. But, it then asks:

*[...] construct the permutation group as a subgroup of a full symmetric
group that is generated by exactly two of the eight elements you have already constructed. Hint: which two elements of $Z_2 \times Z_4$ might you use to generate all of $Z_2 \times Z_4$?*

What I expect is to find two elements of $Z_2 \times Z_4$ which generate $Z_2 \times Z_4$. But, I have been scratching my head since I simply can't see which elements do this.

I know that elements with the highest order possible in $Z_2 \times Z_4$ will have order $lcm(2, 4) = 4$. So I think I have to choose two such elements. But without even considering the permutation group I built, I cannot get those two elements from pen and paper. To convince myself that something is off, I wrote a sage script:

```
generated = set()
for element in G:
    order = element.order()
    assert order in set([1, 2, 4])
    if order == 4:
        generates = [element ** i for i in range(0, 4)]
        generated.update(generates)
```

It outputs:

```
{(),
 (1,2,3,4)(5,6,7,8),
 (1,3)(2,4)(5,7)(6,8),
 (1,4,3,2)(5,8,7,6),
 (1,6,3,8)(2,7,4,5),
 (1,8,3,6)(2,5,4,7)}
```

which clearly isn't my initial group. What am I doing/understanding wrong here?

Comment: I don't understand the link between what you modeled in Sage with $G$ and the group $H = \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_4$. $H$ is the direct product of two cyclic groups. $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are good candidates to generate $H$!

Comment: This is what I obtain after "coding" $\{  (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3) \}$ with $\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, ... \}$ and applying Cayley's theorem. Can you walk me through why $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ are good candidates?

Comment: $(n,m)$ is obtained by summing $n$ times $(1,0)$ and $m$ times $(0,1)$.

Comment: But isn't $|(1, 0)| = 2$ and $|(0, 1)| = 4$? How can these two generate a group of order 8? I'm definitely missing the calculation for generating a group using two group elements. Thanks for your time! Will look this on my own, I think I figured out what I was missing :)